# Elasticsearch NEST PUT Mapping to Add Field / Property

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using the NEST Suggest.Completion query to provide suggestive search.  I already have data in the index and wanted to add a new field "IsActive" to allow me to disable certain documents from appearing in the suggest.

I thought the NEST `Map<>` method would add the new field to all existing documents in the index when run, but it does not.  Is there some way to make it work like that?

I am using Elasticsearch 6.8.0.

**My Object with the new field**

```
[ElasticsearchType(
       IdProperty = "search"
   )]
public class SearchCompletion
{
    public string search { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Use this field for aggregations and sorts
    /// </summary>
    [Keyword]
    public string search_keyword { get; set; }

    public bool isActive { get; set; }  // <---- This is the new field

    /// <summary>
    /// To use for sorting results
    /// since you can't sort by the Completionfield.Weight 
    /// property for some reason
    /// </summary>
    public int weight { get; set; }

    public CompletionField suggest { get; set; }
}
```

**Method to Re-Apply Mapping**

```
    public static void MapSearchCompletions(ElasticClient client, string index)
    {
        var mapResponse = client.Map<SearchCompletion>(m => m
            .Index(index)
            .AutoMap()
       ); //re-apply the index mapping
    }
```

**The PUT request**

```
 PUT /local.project.tests.searchcompletions/searchcompletion/_mapping

{
    "properties": {
        "search": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
        },
        "search_keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "isActive": {
            "type": "boolean"
        },
        "weight": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "suggest": {
            "type": "completion"
        }
    }
}
```

**The result of querying the index after the mapping**

```
GET /local.project.tests.searchcompletions/searchcompletion/_search

{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "local.project.tests.searchcompletions",
        "_type": "searchcompletion",
        "_id": "the",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "search": "the",
          "search_keyword": "the",
          "weight": 1,
          "suggest": {
            "input": [
              "the",
              "the"
            ],
            "weight": 1
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, updating mapping won't change existing documents. To do so, you can use [update_by_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) API.

```
var updateByQueryResponse = await client.UpdateByQueryAsync<Document>(u => u
    .Query(q => q.MatchAll())
    .Script("ctx._source.isActive = true")
    .Refresh());
```

Here is the full example:

```
class Program
{
    public class Document
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
        var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool);
        connectionSettings.DefaultIndex("documents");

        var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

        var deleteIndexResponse = await client.Indices.DeleteAsync("documents");
        var createIndexResponse = await client.Indices.CreateAsync("documents", d => d
            .Map(m => m.AutoMap<Document>()));

        var indexDocument = await client.IndexDocumentAsync(new Document {Id = 1});

        var refreshAsync = client.Indices.RefreshAsync();

        var putMappingResponse = await client.MapAsync<Document>(m => m
            .AutoMap());

        var updateByQueryResponse = await client.UpdateByQueryAsync<Document>(u => u
            .Query(q => q.MatchAll())
            .Script("ctx._source.isActive = true")
            .Refresh());

        var response = await client.GetAsync<Document>(1);

        Console.WriteLine(response.Source.IsActive);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
True
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, that worked, thanks!  I was hoping to have this be something that could keep the document mapping up to date with whatever the base model was automatically (i.e. no magic strings).  So, for example, when I roll out a new version of the API the index mapping would get "auto updated" to the C# model, adding or removing any fields as required. I'll think I'll have to treat this more like what I would do with a SQL database and have "update scripts" that run as part of a new version's deployment.